# Python - Pandas - DataFrame reduce rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a DataFrame like so:

```
ind  col1 col2
1    12   string1  ...
2    23   string2 ...
3    34   string1 ...
4    13   string2 ...
5    17   string3 ...
...  ...  ...     ...
```

I want to collapse the DataFrame so that col2 will be unique. In col1 (and all the other numerical columns), I want to put the median of all the values where col2 was equal.

I know I can extract df[df["col2"] == "stringN"], calculate the medians and build a new DataFrame, but is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to collect the rows by `col2` and then `.median()`:

```
>>> df
   ind  col1     col2
0    1    12  string1
1    2    23  string2
2    3    34  string1
3    4    13  string2
4    5    17  string3
>>> df.groupby("col2")
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x9f41b8c>
>>> df.groupby("col2").median()
         ind  col1
col2              
string1    2    23
string2    3    18
string3    5    17
>>> df.groupby("col2").median().reset_index()
      col2  ind  col1
0  string1    2    23
1  string2    3    18
2  string3    5    17
```

Note that the result has the medians of the `ind` values as well.  See also `.mean()`, `.min()`, `.max()`, or you can roll your own if you'd prefer.